# Powershell strings equal but not equal in try except block

Tags: powershell, try-catch

In attempting to understand the logic of try-catch blocks in Powershell, I am experiencing a failure to terminate from a successful pairing of target string to iterated string element from a hashtable.

```
$stopLoop = $false
$retryWait = 2
$retryCount = 0
$reconnectAttemptMax = 5

$fruits = @('apple','pear','banana','lemon','lime','mango','pineapple','raisins','orange')
$target_fruit = 'pear'
$i = 0

do {
    try {
        if ($fruits[$i] -is $target_fruit ) {
        Write-Host "Found $target_fruit!" }
        $stopLoop = $true
    }
    catch {
        if ($retryCount -eq $reconnectAttemptMax){
            Write-Host "Unable to locate $target_fruit after $retryCount attempts."
            $stopLoop = $true
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Found $($fruits[$i]) not $target_fruit, retrying in $retryWait seconds..."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $retryWait
            $retryCount++
            $i++
        }
    }
} while ($stopLoop -eq $false)
```

When the above code is executed, the second iteration of the loop finds the correct item, but does not terminate from the loop. They are both of String object types, so I assume I am incorrectly nesting the loop criteria.

Result:

```
Found apple not pear, retrying in 2 seconds...
Found pear not pear, retrying in 2 seconds...
Found banana not pear, retrying in 2 seconds...
Found lemon not pear, retrying in 2 seconds...
Found lime not pear, retrying in 2 seconds...
Unable to locate pear after 5 attempts.
```

Comment: `-is` doesn't do what you expect. Change `$fruits[$i] -is $target_fruit` to `$fruits[$i] -eq $target_fruit`

Comment: as aside `@(...)` is not a hashtable, its an array.

Comment: I am not sure I am following what your use case is with this code block. Yet, seems like a lot of code just to do this, ```(($fruits[$i]).CompareTo($target_fruit))```, and streamline this code block. Meaning a simple compare/string match to a  given list. You are not passing a not found time in the list to hit the code segment you are eluding to. Meaning, that ```$Target_fruit```, should not equal anything in the list, if you are trying to test that block. Output to the screen is the default. So ```Write-Host``` is redundant in this case. ***Note: CompareTo is case-sensitive***.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen code does not execute when -eq is used

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that is correct, thank you for making that note!

Comment: @postanote I am trying to test for three scenarios:
1. Success: target exists in array and is identified, with each non-matching iteration called out, before retries are exhausted
2. Limit: target exists in array but retries are exhausted before iteration is reached
3. Not found: target does not exist in array, retries are exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment regarding the `target_fruit` assignment.

```
Clear-Host

$stopLoop            = $false
$retryWait           = 2
$retryCount          = 0
$reconnectAttemptMax = 5
$fruits              = @('apple','pear','banana','lemon','lime','mango','pineapple','raisins','orange')
$target_fruit        = 'DOG'
$i                   = 0

do {
    try {
        if ($fruits[$i] -is $target_fruit ) 
        {"Found $target_fruit!"}
        $stopLoop = $true
    }
    catch 
    {
        if ($retryCount -eq $reconnectAttemptMax)
        {
            Write-Warning -Message "Unable to locate $target_fruit after $retryCount attempts."
            $stopLoop = $true
            Write-Warning -Message 'Exiting the script'
        }
        else 
        {
            "Found $($fruits[$i]) not $target_fruit, retrying in $retryWait seconds..."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $retryWait
            $retryCount++
            $i++
        }
    }
} while ($stopLoop -eq $false)
# Results
<#
Found apple not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
Found pear not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
Found banana not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
Found lemon not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
Found lime not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
WARNING: Unable to locate DOG after 5 attempts.
WARNING: Exiting the script
#>
```

Quick example using CompareTo and your string.

```
$fruits | 
Where-Object {($PSItem).CompareTo($target_fruit) -eq 0}
# Results
<#
pear
#>
```

Using you code block a bit more.

```
$retryWait           = 2
$retryCount          = 0
$reconnectAttemptMax = 5
$fruits              = @('apple','pear','banana','lemon','lime','mango','pineapple','raisins','orange')
$target_fruit        = 'DOG'
$i                   = 0

Try 
{
    do
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "Found $($fruits[$i]) not $target_fruit, retrying in $retryWait seconds..."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $retryWait
        $retryCount++
        $i++
    }
    until (($fruits[$i]).CompareTo($target_fruit) -eq 0)

    "Found $target_fruit!"
}
Catch
{
    Write-Warning -Message "Unable to locate $target_fruit after $retryCount attempts."
    Write-Warning -Message 'Exiting the script'
    Break
}
# Results
<#
WARNING: Found orange not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
WARNING: Found apple not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
WARNING: Found pear not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
WARNING: Found banana not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
WARNING: Found lemon not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
WARNING: Found lime not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
WARNING: Found mango not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
WARNING: Found pineapple not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
WARNING: Found raisins not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
WARNING: Found orange not DOG, retrying in 2 seconds...
WARNING: Unable to locate DOG after 10 attempts.
WARNING: Exiting the script
#>


Clear-Host

$retryWait           = 2
$retryCount          = 0
$reconnectAttemptMax = 5
$fruits              = @('apple','pear','banana','lemon','lime','mango','pineapple','raisins','orange')
$target_fruit        = 'pear'
$i                   = 0

Try 
{
    do
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "Found $($fruits[$i]) not $target_fruit, retrying in $retryWait seconds..."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $retryWait
        $retryCount++
        $i++
    }
    until (($fruits[$i]).CompareTo($target_fruit) -eq 0)

    "Found $target_fruit!"
}
Catch
{
    Write-Warning -Message "Unable to locate $target_fruit after $retryCount attempts."
    Write-Host 'Exiting the script' -ForegroundColor Red
    Break
}
# Results
<#
WARNING: Found apple not pear, retrying in 2 seconds...
Found pear!
#>
```

> See also:
>
> [Everything you wanted to know about exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: the top code does not resolve when a item contained within the array is found before retries are exhausted. The last two examples do not account for retry limits. Am I missing something?

Comment: The very first code sample is your code as posted, and just using ```DOG``` as the search in order to hit the other code path you are asking about. The latter try/catch ones with the difference in the loop call. Notice you are using ```While``` where I am using ```Until```.   See details of the two here, to set your expectations on their use: [PowerShell: Do-While vs. Do-Until vs. While](https://sid-500.com/2019/11/04/powershell-do-while-vs-do-until/). So, your use case is not ```try/catch`` specific catch22, it's the comparisons you are executing as well.

Comment: Also, please read the other ***about Exceptions*** link I provided earlier to help provide deeper edification relevant to terminating and non-terminating errors when implementing ```try/catch``` in your code. Again, ```try/catch``` is not a specific PS thing. It's been in use in programming languages before PS ever existed. So, you can dig more at it as an implementation, without any consideration to PS specifically.

Comment: While I appreciate the link, it does not provide the answer to the question asked. How can the Success, Limit, and Not Found criteria be included within a Do While loop, or is this more of a If, Elseif, Else logic need? I have tried several solutions at this point, and each are missing one component.